# jQuery - Find first div with specific ID inside a Div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So my code always follows the same kind of format:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="firstDiv">
  </div>
</div>
```

Sometimes it's like this (and this is what I want to ignore):

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="banner">
  </div>

  <div id="firstDiv">
  </div>
</div>
```

So what I want to do is

IF the first div inside #container is equal to #firstDiv - add a banner.  else (there's already a banner there) do nothing.

Any help with this would be great!!

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that:

```
if($('#container > div:first').attr('id') == 'banner') {
    //banner exists
} else {
   //banner not exists
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a child selector:

```
div#container > div#firstDiv
```

Comment: it will match the `firstDiv` irrespective of whether it is the first or second child

Answer (score 1):

You can

```js
$('#firstDiv:first-child').before('<div class="banner">banner</div>');
$('#firstDiv2:first-child').before('<div class="banner">banner</div>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="firstDiv">Div</div>
</div>

<div id="container2">
  <div id="banner">Banner</div>
  <div id="firstDiv2">Div</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if($("#container").find("#banner").lenght == 0){
    // You have the banner
}else{
    // you dont`n have the banner
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
(function(){

      if(!$('#firstDiv','#container').length){
           $('#container').prepend(jQuery('<div id="firstDiv">'));
     }

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

With the `children()` selector you get all the children element of `#container`.
With the `first()` you get the first one, and with `attr('id')` you get the id name.

Then you just have to check what id name you have

Example:

```
if($("#container").children().first().attr('id') != "banner"){
     addBanner();
}
```